# How does one parse a complex domain object to JSON object in grails?

Tags: json, grails

Okay first off , I am extremely new to grails. And I am quite stuck at converting a domain object to JSON.

My domain class looks as follows

```
class MoneyTransfer {

    Account fromAccount
    Date sourceTransactionDate
    TransactionStatus sourceTransactionStatus
    String sourceTransactionMessage

    Account toAccount
    Date destinationTransactionDate
    TransactionStatus destinationTransactionStatus
    String destinationTransactionMessage

    double amount

    String note

    Status status

    PianoUser creator

    String errorMessage

    // predefined grails date create & modified & version
    Date dateCreated

    Date lastUpdated

    String uniqueId

}
```

How does one convert such a domain class's object to JSON object ?

I tried using `grails.converters.JSON` and `grails.converters.deep.JSON` as follows

```
class MyTransferController{
     def xyz(){
        MoneyTransfer monetTransferInstance = getMoneyTransferInstance();
        def moneyTransferJson = fundTrasnferInstance as JSON //doesnot work 
    }
}
```

How do I convert my domain class's object to JSON Object? Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by `it does not work`?

Comment: Throws a missing method exception!

Comment: Can you please include the exception in your answer?

Comment: by the way there is a typo in `fundTrasnferInstance as JSON`. Use `monetTransferInstance as JSON`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
import grails.converters.JSON

class MyTransferController {
     def xyz() {
        MoneyTransfer moneyTransferInstance = getMoneyTransferInstance()
        render moneyTransferInstance as JSON 
    }
}
```